# Refresh textfield after submitting

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this code that submits to a database without refresing, but the problem is when its sent, the variables still remains in the textfield

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert.asp",
        data: data
        }).done(function( msg ) {

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

i was thinking if there's a way the variables will disappear from the textfiled after its been sent to the database and even bring an alert which fades automatically when data is saved.

Comment: surely you could have found numerous answers to this with a simple web search!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you'll want to do is add your desired behavior in the callback following the ajax request. Currently you're using "done" as the callback, which in my understanding will execute whenever the ajax  call completes, regardless of success or failure. If that's what you desire, add the textfield clearing and alert code within this callback, otherwise a callback like "success" may be more appropriate.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by an "alert"... If you're referring to an alert box, ie.: alert(), I wouldn't suggest it. This will pause your script until the user clicks the button, thus there is no way to kill the alert once it has been displayed. Also alert boxes aren't the nicest thing to present to the user imo. An alternative would be to define a div somewhere in your page, add the success message to it with jquery within the success/done callback and then set a time out so that it fades (included in my example below). If you're looking for something more elaborate jquery ui has some alternatives to alert boxes in their widgets.

Maybe this code can give you some ideas to get started:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert.asp",
        data: data
        }).success(function() {

            $("#feedback").append("<div class='messages' style='border:1px green solid; padding:2px; margin:5px;'>successfully submitted!</div>");

            setTimeout(function() { 
                $(".messages").fadeOut(function(){
                    $(".messages").remove();
                }); 
            }, 1000);

            $("input[type=text]").val("");

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Where there's a div with an id="feedback" where you'd like to display messages.

Comment: Thanks so much. it worked perfectly and just the way i expected. Jesus bless you

Comment: its working properly but was wondering if the success message could appear at the position of the cursor. cos i'm using it on nested records

Comment: You could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/UvnKA/3/
Note that this changes from a submit event to a click event in order to capture the mouse coords, and that I changed the url argument to blank so that it works on jsfiddle.

Comment: when i click on test nothing happens

Comment: You have to click "Run" on the top menu first.

Comment: ok, i did and it worked but when i copied back to my server this time with the new code, it doesn't submit all at

Comment: I had to change the url attribute to "" in order to make it work on jsfiddle.  If you've already changed that back I'm not sure what else I can help you with. These are mostly just ideas to help you in the right direction, you'll have to look into them a bit more yourself depending on your specific setup.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
 $('input[type=text]').val(''); // select all text inputs and assign value of ''
```

Your code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert.asp",
        data: data
        }).done(function( msg ) {
             $('input[type=text]').val('');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: with the supplied, it does not even submit and the page also refreshes

Comment: This should work. You need only copy the portion wrapped in the done callback. If it doesn't, I would check for errors in your browser console.

Comment: I took your code(that should work) and added a simple line that says 'clear all my text input values' after your ajax call was done(i.e. after the response from the call was recieved).
This shouldn't harm any of you posts and should not refresh pages. Check what you did wrong..BTW from what I see here your trying to prevent a page submission and to do it the ajax way. Why not remove the submit button and handle a "onclick" on a regular button?